# Experience selling with Getty Images

Tags: stock-photography, selling

Have you ever sold any pictures through Getty images? Are you happy with the experience?

1. What did you think about the pricing they proposed? Did you think you could sell more for a smaller price?
2. What did you think about the royalties? What did you get - 20%? 30%? Did your feel fairly rewarded for your work?
3. Any problems getting the money? Was the payment on time?

Comment: People will answer #4 anyway. :) But #5 is out of place here.  A simpler question is better (people tend to ignore later subquestions anyway), and I'd stick with just 1-3.

Comment: @Roger - edited as per your comment. Will move no.5 to a separate question.

Comment: Perhaps change the title to something like "Experience selling on Getty images". I originally thought this was from a buyer perspective.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be have a look at Flickr discussions, given that there is probably little experience with Getty in our current user base here (we're a pretty small bunch). Getty has an arrangement with Flickr that allows them to contact users who are interested in selling and so the experience of that is probably going to appear somewhere in their discussion groups.